# New to Magento phtml code doesn't show

Tags: magento2, theme, phtml

I've been trying to add phtml to my custom theme but it doesn't show for example

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_view_custom_block" before="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_block.phtml"/>
```

path for xml is `<theme_name>\<theme>\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml`

path is `<theme_name>\<theme>\Magento_Catalog\product\view\custom_block.phtml`

the **`template=""`** what should I put inside the double quotes? Did I do this right?

I'm using Magento 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add it like this.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.custom.block" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_block.phtml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

> app/code/theme_name/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_block.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create **`custom_block.phtml`** and place your code

> app/code/theme_name/theme/Magento_Catalog/product/view/custom_block.phtml

```
<?php

echo "Called custom phtml file";

?>
```

If any query let me know.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: I'm getting the error -----

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_block.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'custom.block'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_block.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'custom.block'
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1095]

Comment: please share your full phtml path.